# Irreducible components of tensor product representations.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $(\rho,V)$ be an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$, and let $W$ be a vector space. Then clearly $(\rho\otimes\text{Id}_{W},V\otimes W)$ is also a representation of $G$. I would like to show that each sub-representation of $V\otimes W$ is of the form $V\otimes U$ for some $U\subset W$, but I'm not sure where to start.

My suspicion is that I need to define some sort of intertwining projection onto $V$, but I'm not sure what this would look like. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$\textbf{Edit}$: Ok, I think I've made some progress. Let $X\subset V\otimes W$ be an invariant subspace. Given a linear form $f:W\to\mathbb{C}$, one can define a linear map $\phi:X \to V$ by extending $\text{Id}_{V}\otimes f$ by linearity. The map $\phi$ intertwines $(\rho,V)$ with the subrepresentation supported on $X$. We can now utilise the irreducibility of $V$, which implies that either $\phi(X)=0$ or $\phi(X)=V$. I feel like this is on the right track, but am not sure of the next step. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It is not true it the representation is not absolutely irreducible.

Comment: @DerekHolt Hi Derek, thanks for your reply. Could you possibly explain what you mean by 'absolutely irreducible'? I don't think I've come across this term before.

Comment: For a representation over a not-necessarily-algebraically-closed field $k$, absolutely irreducible means irreducible over $\bar{k}$. But presumably in your question you're working over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok I see, thanks. Yes, I'm only interested in representations over $\mathbb{C}$.